# CONFIGURE A STRONG PASSWORD POLICY - Failed Attempts, password-auth

Tags: linux, rhel

Yet another question regarding security scanning. What does security scanning output mean?

```
Result: FAILED

Actual Value: The command returned : 

auth        required                                     pam_faillock.so preauth silent
auth        required                                     pam_faillock.so authfail
account     required                                     pam_faillock.so

Policy Value: cmd: grep ""pam_faillock.so"" /etc/pam.d/password-auth | awk '{print} END {if (NR == 0) print ""Account lockout for 'password-auth' not set""}'
dont_echo_cmd: YES
expect: deny[\s]*=[\s]*5[\s]*unlock_time[\s]*=[\s]*300
system: Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

The scan expects to see options `deny = 5 unlock_time = 300` (the amount of whitespace may vary) somewhere on the `pam_faillock.so` lines in the `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` file.

It did not see them, and so this part of the scan is marked as failed.

Apparently, the scan executes the command specified in `Policy Value: cmd:` line, and the output of that command should match the Perl-Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE for short) on the `expect:` line.

The doubled double quotes (`""`) on the `Policy Value: cmd:` line may be a result of how the scanner itself is implemented. If you try running the command yourself, you might want to remove the doubling:

```
grep "pam_faillock.so" /etc/pam.d/password-auth | awk '{print} END {if (NR == 0) print "Account lockout for 'password-auth' not set"}'
```